# How to set TTL for query_log in Clickhouse using sql?

Tags: database, clickhouse

I want to set ttl for `system.query_log` table using sql.

I know I can set it using the `ttl` element in the xml file like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7ZQ7.png)

But I want to achieve this using sql query. This is because I'm enabling query log for a particular profile using sql query and I want to set the ttl for the same using sql as well. Cannot find a doc that helps me do so. Please help.

Comment: see https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/ttl

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's possible to use a SQL command to modify the TTL of the `system.query_log` table (which I think it is), you will lose the setting on a server restart.

To permanently have a TTL rule on `query_log`, you will need to configure it in an XML config file

Comment: actually you will lose it only during the table re-creation. For example during some!!! upgrades (when the structure of the table changes) or after `droptable`.